# e-mail validation on windows form

Tags: c#

i am using windows forms.

I just want to validate my textbox ( or masked textbox ) for e-mail id.

Can any one tell me the idea for that?

Comment: You could use regex?
Google c# regex and Regex email...

Comment: 14 questions and not one accepted answer?

Comment: Fredrik Mörk is right, mark answered questions or you will not get answer in the future

Answer (score 4):

Try to use regular expression like
`@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the constructor of  the [System.Net.Mail.MailAdress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8.aspx) class that represents mail addresses.

Try to initialize an instance with your string and catch the exception, that is thrown if the validation failed. Something like this:

```
try
{
   new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(this.textBox.Text);
}
catch(ArgumentException)
{
   //textBox is empty
}
catch(FormatException)
{
   //textBox contains no valid mail address
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try regular expression

```
@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

or check your email address in code

```
string email=textbox1.text;
if(email.lastindexof("@")>-1)
{
//valid
}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`string email=textbox1.text;`

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex expr= new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]{2,28}[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");`

```
`if (expr.IsMatch(email))
            MessageBox.Show("valid");

        else MessageBox.Show("invalid");`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void emailTxt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)

{

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rEmail = new    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");

        if (emailTxt.Text.Length > 0 && emailTxt.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
            if (!rEmail.IsMatch(emailTxt.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("check email id");
                emailTxt.SelectAll();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use this way and it's working well for me.

```
/* Add this reference */

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

---------------------------

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text))
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");
    if (!reg.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text))
    {
        Mensaje += "* El email no es válido. \n\n";
        isValid = false;
    }
}
```